# building from command line without declaring every function

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to build multi-file project. How do I use ino build in a way that doesn't give me a bunch of not declared in this scope error when using multiple files like Arduino IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already working on the command line you might want to learn about the [C++ build process.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11557872/2036917)
Then start to learn about [SCONS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54742/2036917). Once you understand this you do not want to mess with Arduino IDE + INO files anymore. A suitable sconstruct can be found [here.](http://code.google.com/p/arscons/source/browse/SConstruct)

Comment: your link to "here" appears to be out of date?